# does setOnClickListener force button to be clickable?

Tags: java, android, onclick

I have an android ButtonView,

I set it to be unclickable:

```
 mDoneBtn.setClickable(false);
```

later I set an onClickListener to it

```
mDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

does the latter make the button to be clickable again?

Comment: @User22791 you are wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you write:

```
mDoneBtn.setClickable(false);
```

Then you set onClick:

```
mDoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}
```

The button will trigger onClick event.

But if you set as:

```
mDoneBtn.setEnabled(false);
```

and then set your onClick, the onClick event will not be triggered.

**Requested Edit:**

*setClickable* automatically becomes *true* if *onClickListenner* is implemented. if you do *setEnabled(false)*, until it is set to true, it will *not be* clickable even if you implement onClickListenner.

Comment: you wrote the same order twice

Comment: they are different.

up: setClickable

down: setEnabled

Comment: what is the difference btw?

Comment: setClickable automatically becomes true if onClickListenner is implemented. if you do setEnabled(false), until it is set to true, it will not be clickable even if you implement onClickListenner.

Comment: can you add this to you answer? it's all true to API 8 ?

Comment: sure, they are both introduced in API1

Answer (score 4):

From `View` source:

```
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
        if (!isClickable()) {
            setClickable(true);
        }
        getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

I guess you can figure out the answer.

EDIT: valid for API level 19

Comment: it happens for API 8 as well. If i change the order the button isn't clickable.